# API key from api.football-data.org

Tags: java, mysql, json, api

How do I use my API key from https://api.football-data.org in my java class and do I have to keep requesting access with the key every time I gather data from a link? Say if I switch from one method to another where I use a different link do i have to enter my API key in again?

I am new to java and I have 0 idea on how to implement an API key can you guys help me out.

PS the comments next to my code are irrelevant :/ for the most part

This is the class I am working with:

```
package org.json;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafxapplication1.CheckConnection;


public class Retriever {
    public CheckConnection check = new CheckConnection();

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
      return json;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

  public void apikey() throws Exception{

      //WHAT DO I DO HERE

  }      

     public void fixtures(int i) throws IOException, JSONException, SQLException {
        int Counter = 0;//declaration of Counter used later on 
        //fixtureURL array which contains all the URLs
        String[] fixtureURL = {"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/fixtures"};
        List <String> FixtureURL = Arrays.asList(fixtureURL);//puts array into list
        int FixtureSize = FixtureURL.size();//length of FixtureURL list   
        for(int x = 1; x <= FixtureSize; x++){//for loop: loops from 1 to the length of the FixtureURL list times
            JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(FixtureURL.get(Counter));//reads url based on the counter value which represents the position in the FixtureURL list which has the all the relevant URLs
            JSONArray fixtures = (JSONArray) json.get("fixtures");//json dictionary containing all fixture data
            for(i = 0; i < fixtures.length();i++) {//for loop: loops the length of the fixture dictionary to ensure each element has been looked at; loop increments by one
                JSONObject innerObj = fixtures.getJSONObject(i);//each element in fixture contains fixture info for the 2 teams in the match           
                for(Iterator it = innerObj.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {//loops for each element in fixture to gather data from each element which will essentially be the columns in my fixture table in my football database; will loop as long as true value is returned - as long as there are elements in fixture
                    String key = (String)it.next();
                    System.out.println(key + ":" + innerObj.get(key));
                    ///////////////////////////////////////// fixture table columnn variables below                    
                    String date = (String) innerObj.getString("date");//gets the date of a fixture from the fixture url
                    String status = (String) innerObj.getString("status");//gets the status of a fixture from the fixture url
                    int matchday = (int) innerObj.getInt("matchday");//gets the matchday number for a fixture from the fixture url                    
                    String homeTeamName = (String) innerObj.getString("homeTeamName");//gets the home team name for a fixture from the fixture url
                    String awayTeamName = (String) innerObj.getString("awayTeamName");//gets the away team name for a fixture from the fixture url
                    JSONObject result = (JSONObject) innerObj.get("result");//
                    int goalsHomeTeam = 0;
                    int goalsAwayTeam = 0;
                    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Finished")){
                        goalsHomeTeam = (int) result.get("goalsHomeTeam"); //gets the home team goals for a fixture from the fixture url 
                        goalsAwayTeam = (int) result.get("goalsAwayTeam"); //gets the away team goals for a fixture from the fixture url 
                        System.out.println(goalsHomeTeam);                          
                    }                    
                    int goals = goalsHomeTeam + goalsAwayTeam;//calculates the total amount of goals in a fixture 
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    Connection con2 = check.connection;//calls the Db connection class to make a connection with the football databse           
                    Statement stateF = con2.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rsF = stateF.executeQuery("Select FixtureID, Date, HomeTeamName, Status, Matchday from fixtures");
                    //sql query to gather data from the various columns named above from the fixture table and put them all in a ResultSet
                    while(rsF.next()){
                        int fid = rsF.getInt(1);
                        String fdate = rsF.getString(2);
                        String htn = rsF.getString(3);                        
                        String fstat = rsF.getString(4);
                        int fmday =rsF.getInt(5);                        
                        ////////////////////////////////////
                        if(!htn.equalsIgnoreCase(homeTeamName)&&!fdate.equalsIgnoreCase(date)){
                            PreparedStatement Fstate = null; 
                            Statement Fstate2 = con2.createStatement();
                            Statement Fstate3 = con2.createStatement();
                            Statement Fstate4 = con2.createStatement();
                            try{                               
                                Fstate = con2.prepareStatement("insert into fixtures values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");//enters in a new row containg all the team data extracted from the league table url  
                                Fstate.setInt(1, fid+1);//takes existing id from the team table in the football database and adds 1 to create new team id and assigns it to the first column in a new row
                                ResultSet rsF2 = Fstate2.executeQuery("select LeagueID, TeamID, TeamName from teams");                            
                                while(rsF2.next()){
                                    int LeagueID = rsF2.getInt(1);//gets league id from teams table in football database
                                    int TeamID = rsF2.getInt(2);
                                    String TeamName = rsF2.getString(3);
                                    if(homeTeamName.equalsIgnoreCase(TeamName)){
                                        Fstate.setInt(2, LeagueID);//assigns team name from teams table url to column 2 in a new row                                
                                        Fstate.setInt(5, TeamID);
                                        Fstate.setString(6, homeTeamName);
                                        Fstate.setInt(7, goalsHomeTeam);
                                        Fstate.setString(9, awayTeamName);
                                        Fstate.setInt(10, goalsAwayTeam);
                                        ResultSet rsF3 = Fstate3.executeQuery("select TeamID from teams where TeamName = '"+ awayTeamName +"'");
                                        while(rsF3.next()){
                                            int awtid = rsF3.getInt(1);
                                            Fstate.setInt(8, awtid);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if(awayTeamName.equalsIgnoreCase(TeamName)){
                                        Fstate.setInt(2, LeagueID);//assigns team name from teams table url to column 2 in a new row                                
                                        Fstate.setInt(8, TeamID);
                                        Fstate.setString(9, awayTeamName);
                                        Fstate.setInt(10, goalsAwayTeam);
                                        Fstate.setString(6, homeTeamName);
                                        Fstate.setInt(7, goalsHomeTeam);
                                        ResultSet rsF4 = Fstate4.executeQuery("select TeamID from teams where TeamName = '"+ homeTeamName +"'");
                                        while(rsF4.next()){
                                            int htid = rsF4.getInt(1);
                                            Fstate.setInt(5, htid);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                Fstate.setString(3, date);        
                                Fstate.setInt(4, matchday);//assigns team logo URL from league table url to column 4 in a new row
                                Fstate.setString(11, status);//assigns team matches played from league table url to column 5 in a new row
                                Fstate.setInt(12, goals);//assigns team wins from league table url to column 6 in a new row                 
                                int k = Fstate.executeUpdate();
                                if (k>0){
                                    System.out.println("Transferred");                                      
                                }                 
                               else{
                                    System.out.println("Not Transferred");       
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                System.out.println(e);
                                fixtures(i++);
                            }
                        }
                        if(htn.equalsIgnoreCase(homeTeamName)&&fdate.equalsIgnoreCase(date)){
                            if(!fstat.equalsIgnoreCase(status)){
                                PreparedStatement Sstate = null;                 
                                try{             
                                    Sstate = con2.prepareStatement("Update fixtures set Status="+status+" where FixtureID="+fid+"");
                                    int s = Sstate.executeUpdate();
                                    if (s>0){
                                       System.out.println("Transferred");                                       
                                    }
                                    else{
                                       System.out.println("Not Transferred");
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                   System.out.println(e);                                   
                                }                            
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }         
    }       
}
```

Comment: is this specifically for NFL? because nfl.com has a much better API you can use for free and its easier than what your code looks like. i feel like im looking into a spaghetti bowl.

Comment: Nah it's real football aka soccer